# Getting folder actions to run a shell script

Tags: terminal, applescript

I'm trying to to write an applescript that will run any shell script that is dropped on a particular folder on my network.

I've been trying with:

```
on adding folder items to target_folder after receiving this_script
    tell application "Terminal" to open this_script
end adding folder items to
```

But I'm not having any luck.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: Make sure the shell scripts have the name extension `.command`. Otherwise they won't open.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try:

`on adding folder items to target_folder after receiving added_items do shell script " " end adding folder items to`

See [Technical Note TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html) on how to format your shell script.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The script runs fine when typed into the terminal. I think it might have to do something with the script not being executable. I get better results when I run a chmod +x on it first. I just have no idea how to write the syntax for doing that first and then running the script.

Comment: Edit your question above and add your shell script so people can see it.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet cash money it's because you have some characters that need escaping in your shell script. Post your script.